# Looping ArcPy function through each point in shapefile

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, for-loop

I have been trying to create a geoprocessing tool to delineate watershed basins for each point in a shapefile (parameter 1; CROSSING). The code below returns three 'basins', but they are all identical to each other. How can I alter this code to return a unique 'basin' for each point in 'CROSSING'?

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.env.addOutputsToMap = True
#DEFINE PARAMETERS & zLimit
DEM         = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) #digital elevation model
CROSSING    = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) #shp containing the stream crossings
PARCEL      = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2) #polygon for clipping raster layer
EXTENT      = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3) #search radius for SnapPourPoint()
LOCATION    = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4) #output file path
zLimit      = 3.2808                      #for converting meters to feet
#CHECK OUT REQUIRED EXTENSION
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
#CLIPPING RASTER LAYER TO SMALLER AREA AROUND THE PARCEL
AOI = arcpy.Buffer_analysis(PARCEL,'AOI',10000)
USR = ExtractByMask(DEM,AOI)
arcpy.AddMessage('Raster optimization completed')
#GENERATING REQUIRED RASTER LAYERS
outFill = Fill(USR,zLimit)
outFlowDir = FlowDirection(outFill)
outFlowAcc = FlowAccumulation(outFlowDir)
#SETUP FOR LOOP
crossings = arcpy.SearchCursor(CROSSING)
i = 1
for OBJECTID in crossings:
    outSnapPoint = SnapPourPoint(CROSSING, outFlowAcc, EXTENT)
    arcpy.AddMessage('Flow direction analysis completed')
    watersheds = Watershed(outFlowDir,outSnapPoint,"VALUE")
    arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion(watersheds,LOCATION+"/BASIN_"+str(i)+'.shp')
    arcpy.AddMessage('Basin '+str(i)+' completed')
    arcpy.Delete_management(outSnapPoint)
    arcpy.Delete_management(watersheds)
    i = i + 1
arcpy.AddMessage('Watershed basins have been drawn, and are located in '+LOCATION)   
#DELETE EXCESS SHAPEFILES
EXCESS = [outFill,outFlowDir,outFlowAcc,outSnapPoint,watersheds,AOI,USR]
arcpy.Delete_management(EXCESS)
```

Comment: Do *not* use `arcpy.SearchCursor` in new code. Only use DA cursors. They are fast and Pythonic.

Comment: PEP8 asserts a standard for naming variables, and ALLUPPERCASE doesn't play a starring role. If you start out writing clean, portable code, you won't have break any bad habits later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following some observations...

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(CROSSING, ["OID@"]) as cursor:
  for row in cursor:
    where_clause = "OBJECTID = '{}'".format(row[0])
    layer_Select=arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(CROSSING, 'NEW_SELECTION', where_clause)
    outSnapPoint = SnapPourPoint(layer_Select, outFlowAcc, EXTENT)
    arcpy.AddMessage('Flow direction analysis completed')
    watersheds = Watershed(outFlowDir,outSnapPoint,"VALUE")
    arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion(watersheds,LOCATION+"/BASIN_"+str(i)+'.shp')
    arcpy.AddMessage('Basin '+str(i)+' completed')
    arcpy.Delete_management(outSnapPoint)
    arcpy.Delete_management(watersheds)
    i = i + 1
```

And if it doesn't work, you might need to export the selected feature to another shapefile before using it...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some [fields in your SearchCursor](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/searchcursor-class.htm).
Your code should look like this:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(CROSSING, ["OID@"]) as cursor:
  for row in cursor:
    outSnapPoint = SnapPourPoint(CROSSING, outFlowAcc, EXTENT)
    arcpy.AddMessage('Flow direction analysis completed')
    watersheds = Watershed(outFlowDir,outSnapPoint,"VALUE")
    arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion(watersheds,LOCATION+"/BASIN_"+str(i)+'.shp')
    arcpy.AddMessage('Basin '+str(i)+' completed')
    arcpy.Delete_management(outSnapPoint)
    arcpy.Delete_management(watersheds)
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: Whilst I believe you are correct in improving the cursor, does this code work? Because the input into SnapPourPoint, never changes? You keep feeding the same layer to it. Either extract out each point or apply a selection to get each unique point.

Comment: `i` is never initialized. Use `for i,row in enumerate(cursor,start=1)` instead. Plus string math is obtuse (use `str.format` instead).

Comment: i is instanciated at line 24 in his code... I just corrected the part of the code where the issue was (from my point of view). But I agree with you, the enumerate function is much better.

Comment: I just realised that you are correct, the SnapPourPoint must be a feature. He will need to export each point before using this function.